# Pandas Plot Bar Fixed Range Missing Values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm plotting a bar chart with data that I have in a pandas.DataFrame. My code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

from datetime import datetime


start_year = 2000
date_range = [ i + start_year for i in range(datetime.today().year - start_year)]

data = pd.DataFrame([
    [2015, 100], [2016, 110], [2017, 105], [2018, 109], [2019, 110], [2020, 116], [2021, 113]
], columns=["year", "value"])

chart = data.plot.bar(
    x="year",
    y="value",
    # xticks=date_range # , 
    xlim=[date_range[0], date_range[-1]]
)
plot.show()
```

The resulting plot is:

[image: Bar plot]

I have to plot several of these, for which data may start from 2000 and finish in 2010, then another dataframe that has data that starts in 2010 and ends in the current year.

In order to make these plots visually comparable, I would like for all to start at the same year, 2000 in this example, and finish the current year. If no value is present for a given year, then 0 can be used. In this case, as example, I've used the year 2000, but it could also start from the year 2005, 2006 or 2010.

How can I achieve what I'm looking for? I've tried setting xticks and xlim, but with xticks, the data gets skewed all towards one side, as if there were thousands of values in between. It is strange since I'm using int values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your dataframe so that it has all years you want.  **right** `merge()` to a dataframe that has all required years

```
data = pd.DataFrame([
    [2015, 100], [2016, 110], [2017, 105], [2018, 109], [2019, 110], [2020, 116], [2021, 113]
], columns=["year", "value"])

# NB range is zero indexed, hence endyear + 1
data.merge(pd.DataFrame({"year":range(2010,2021+1)}), on="year", how="right").plot(kind="bar", x="year", y="value")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already used it and forgot about it. Though, I was hoping for a more "native" solution. I'll wait a couple of days and then mark this answer as accepted if no other answer has a better solution